# Does ClearML have accounting of information security events

Tags: logging, clearml

ClearML is one of the most famous MLOps tools existing. It has logging of machine learning processes, however I couldn't find any information regarding its system of accounting of **information security events**.

My question is: does ClearML have such system? Does it register/log events of client-server interaction? If ClearML does, then what format is used?

Answer (score 0):

The events are logged under the respective docker logs for each of the containers that the environment is comprised of. For example, to get the interactions with the webserver you could use:

```bash
docker logs clearml-webserver -f
```

The `-f` flag makes it continuously update which is handy when debugging. An example output:

```bash
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:05:04 +0000] "GET /version.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/datasets/simple/1a95980ac0214f16acb1b9fc4c53da30/experiments/9d59318cd5914f4bba99251b6c50ec2d?columns=selected&columns=name&columns=hyperparams.properties.version&columns=tags&columns=status&columns=project.name&columns=users&columns=started&columns=last_update&order=-last_update&filter=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:06:22 +0000] "GET /version.json HTTP/1.1" 200 487 "http://localhost:8080/datasets/simple/38d6b19dc3064b9d9db25a70cbf8ff89/experiments/d8966465def843b08f5868cc0dd1baa9?columns=selected&columns=name&columns=hyperparams.properties.version&columns=tags&columns=status&columns=project.name&columns=users&columns=started&columns=last_update&order=-last_update&filter=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:06:29 +0000] "GET /version.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/datasets" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:06:35 +0000] "GET /version.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/datasets/simple/1a95980ac0214f16acb1b9fc4c53da30/experiments/9d59318cd5914f4bba99251b6c50ec2d?columns=selected&columns=name&columns=hyperparams.properties.version&columns=tags&columns=status&columns=project.name&columns=users&columns=started&columns=last_update&order=-last_update&filter=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:07:29 +0000] "GET /version.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/datasets/simple/1a95980ac0214f16acb1b9fc4c53da30/experiments/9d59318cd5914f4bba99251b6c50ec2d?columns=selected&columns=name&columns=hyperparams.properties.version&columns=tags&columns=status&columns=project.name&columns=users&columns=started&columns=last_update&order=-last_update&filter=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022:14:07:41 +0000] "POST /api/v2.20/projects.get_all_ex HTTP/1.1" 200 1053 "http://localhost:8080/projects" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" "-"
```